# Angular Application Data Binding is Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linq, wcf

I am consuming wcf rest service into angular js application . I am trying to get account information based on account number . but the problem is its displaying text Account_Type three times then showing the values .

Here is the method code .

```
  public string AccountDetails(string Account_Number)
        {
            var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = w.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = (decimal?)0M,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                    Date = w.Date,
                     Account_Type=null,  
                    Account_Holder_Tittle = null,
                    Account_Holder_FirstName =null,
                    Account_Holder_LastName = null
                }).Union(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(d => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = d.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = (decimal?)0M,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                    Date = d.Date,
                    Account_Type = null,
                    Account_Holder_Tittle = null,
                    Account_Holder_FirstName = null,
                    Account_Holder_LastName = null
                })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
                .Union(context.Current_Account_Details.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(e => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)0M,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)0M,
                    Date = e.Account_Creation_Date,
                    Account_Type=e.Account_Type,  
                    Account_Holder_Tittle = null,
                    Account_Holder_FirstName =null,
                    Account_Holder_LastName = null

                }))
                .Union(context.Current_Account_Holder_Details.Where(x=>x.Account_Number ==accountNumber).Select(d=> new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = d.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = null,
                    Deposit =null,
                    Withdrawal = null,
                    Date = null,
                    Account_Type = null,
                    Account_Holder_Tittle =d.Tittle,
                    Account_Holder_FirstName=d.Account_Holder_First_Name,
                    Account_Holder_LastName=d.Account_Holder_Last_Name


                }));
                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                return js.Serialize(inOut);
            }
        }
```

Here is the code .

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.IsVisible = false;
            $scope.Search = function () {
                var post = $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/AccountDetails/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Number),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                });

                post.then(function (response) { // .success(function(data => .then(function(response
                    var data = response.data; // extract data from resposne
                    $scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data); // eval(data.d) => JSON.parse(data)
                    $scope.IsVisible = true;
                }, function (err) {
                    $window.alert(err);
                });

            }
            $scope.grandTotal = function () {
                return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
                    var valueToAdd = parseFloat(m.Deposit);
                    if (isNaN(valueToAdd))
                        return previousTotal;
                    return previousTotal + valueToAdd;
                }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal
            }
            $scope.grandTotal1 = function () {
                return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
                    var valueToAdd = parseFloat(m.Withdrawal);
                    if (isNaN(valueToAdd))
                        return previousTotal;
                    return previousTotal + valueToAdd;
                }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal
            }

        });
    </script>


    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Account Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Number" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()" />
        <hr />
        <br />         


        <div ng-repeat="m in Customers" ng-show="IsVisible">Account Type:{{m.Account_Type}}</div>       



    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the scrren shot when i run the application .

[image]

Comment: because you have ng-repeat

Comment: i am good! whatsup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need Account_Type, you don't need an **`ng-repeat`** here. just assign the value to the $scope variable

```
 $scope.Account_Type = details[0].Account_Type;
```